# Are there any rigging (posing) libraries for JavaScript?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a website where you can drag body parts to make a character do a pose. I'm currently using Canvas and FabricJS and I want my images to have 'body parts'.

[This video](https://youtu.be/fOrpLV2nhgo?t=95) *(watch in slow speeds)* showcases exactly what I'm after.

The video above shows that when double-clicking on a body part, it will move to wherever you move your mouse to. The highlighted part is the part that will be movable. There are presets and things that would be useful but at the moment, I'm only looking for if such a thing is possible.

If there is no way to do it with Canvas or Fabric, do you know of any libraries I can use to get this to work?

Comment: This is probably "off-topic" since it is a request for library or software recommendations, but I'm interested to see if there are any good answers... I've used processing.js for this in the past. P5.js had an SVG library but it is a bit out of date and unmaintained.

Comment: What do you mean by "for this in the past"? Image posing/rigging?

Comment: A couple of years ago I did a proof of concept using processing.js for image posing/rigging. A virtual articulated paper doll if you would.